# al hacer click en un boton mostrado por while , solo me arroja datos del primer recorrido del while, aunque haga click en el segundo boton mostrado

Tags: php, array, while

estoy empezando en php y ocupo carrito de compras con sesiones, los productos los muestro por medio de la base de datos con un while y en cada while hay un boton con el id del producto y al momento de hacer click en el boton, llama a una funcion de js donde recibe el id y las piezas y luego las manda a otra funcion que utiliza ajax para mandar todos los datos a un archivo php  en donde creo un array donde guardo todos los datos del producto id,nombre,precio etc luego ese array lo guardo en una sesion "pedidos" con un subindice igual al id del producto , el problema es que cuando le doy en agregar a un producto que no sea el primero mostrado, no lo manda, pero si funciona con el primer producto mostrado,  no se que hacer la verdad ya he buscado pero nada que doy , dejo anexado el codigo

aqui muestro los productos y el boton ejecuta la funcion de js

```
  <?php
   foreach ($resultado as $registros) {
   $datos=$registros['ID_PRODUCTO'];
  ?>
 <li>
 <img class="imagenesproductos"src="<?php echo 
 $registros['DIRECCION_IMAGEN']; ?>" alt="">
 <h1><?php echo $registros['DESCRIPCION'] ;?></h1>
 <p class="precio">PRECIO: <?php echo $registros['PRECIO']; ?> </p>
 <p class="descripcion"><?php echo $registros['descripcion_producto'] ;?> 
 </p>
 <p>Piezas:<p>
  <input type="number" name="piezas" id="piezas" min="0" checked 
  placeholder="Numeros de piezas">
  <input type="hidden" id="id_producto" name="" value="<?php echo $datos;? 
  >">
  <input type="submit" name="" value="">
  <button type="button" onclick="productos()" name="agregar" id="agregarp"      
  value="" >Agregar</button>
  </li>
 <?php
 }
 ?>
```

en la funcion rescato los valores del producto y de las piezas seleccionadas
y los mando a otra funcion que se encarga de enviarlo a un archivo php

```
 function productos(){
      id=$('#id_producto').val();
      piezas=$('#piezas').val();
       agregarpedido(id,piezas);
}
```

funcion con ajax

```
function agregarpedido(id,piezas){
  cadena="id=" + id +
  "&piezas=" + piezas
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"../php/pedidos.php",
    data:cadena,
    success:function(respuesta){
          alertify.success("Producto agregado");
    }

  });
}
```

archivo php aqui creo sesiones y guardo los registros en la sesion

```
<?php
  require_once('../funciones/bd_conexion.php');
  session_start();

  $pedidos=array();

  if (isset($_SESSION['pedidos']))
    $pedidos=$_SESSION['pedidos'];
  }


 $id_producto=$_POST['id'];
  $sql=("SELECT * FROM producto where ID_PRODUCTO ='$id_producto' ");
  $resultado=$conn->query($sql);
  $registros=$resultado->fetch_assoc();
  $item=array(
  'id'=>$id_producto,
  'producto'=>$registros['DESCRIPCION'],
  'precio'=>$registros['PRECIO'],
  'piezas'=>$_POST['piezas']
  );

  if (!empty($pedidos)) {
    foreach ($pedidos as $recorrido) {
    if ($recorrido['id']==$id_producto) {
    $item['piezas']=$recorrido['piezas'] + $item['piezas'];
      }
    }
  }
  $item['subtotal']=$item['precio'] * $item['piezas'];;
  $_SESSION['pedidos'][$id_producto]=$item;



 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que utilizas la misma id_producto en todos los input,  esto hace que al llamar a `$('#id_producto').val();` te devuelva la primera coincidencia que encuentra.

Una solución al problema sería añadir al onclik el parametro que le quieres pasar tal que así:

```
onclick="productos(<?php echo $datos;? 
  >)"
```

Y en caso de que sea String así:

```
onclick="productos('<?php echo $datos;? 
      >')"
```

Comment: mchas gracias esa es la solucion te lo agradezco